# m2Eclipse "No such file or directory" error when child modules depend on each other

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a multi-module Maven project, imported into Eclipse.

Let's say the structure is:

```
Parent
|
|--ChildA
|
|--ChildB
```

The problem I have is that if there is a dependency from ChildA to ChildB (or vice versa) then a "No such file or directory" error is displayed in Eclipse (location line 1 of the child pom with the dependency).

We currently have two 'solutions' for this, neither of which are very satisfactory:

1. Ignore the error.  This works, but it's annoying when you generally want to see 0 errors in the problems view.
2. Turn off workspace resolution for the project.  Again, this works but you lose a lot of the power of Eclipse.  For example, Find Workspace Dependencies does not show everything (essential when refactoring) and if you change a module then you have to do an explicit Run As->Maven Install and Update Projects before your workspace returns to a consistent state.

I am now using Eclipse Luna (m2eclipse 1.5.0) and first noticed it in Juno (m2eclipse 1.3.0.20121216-1819  It did not happen in Helios  (m2eclipse 1.3.0.20130129-0926).  Using Helios is no longer an option having moved onto Java 7.

A command line `mvn clean install` works, of course.

Any help would be most appreciated as this is seriously affecting my productivity currently.

Comment: A cyclic dependendy sounds bad. No matter what Maven does. You might better refactor those parts out to a third module to not have a cyclic dependency.

Comment: I don't think the OP is indicating a cyclic dependency, right?

Comment: @user714965 OP doesn't have a cyclic dependency.  OP mentions "a dependency from ChildA to ChildB (**or** vice versa)" not "a dependency from ChildA to ChildB (**and** vice versa)".

Answer (score 1):

I believe I just fixed this problem on my local project.  I was able to get things to resolve by running

```
mvn clean eclipse:clean
```

And then rebuilding in eclipse.  That seemed to flush out all of the latent configuration issues.